# How can I create a simple file versioning via shell script?

Tags: command-line, version-control

Is it possible to make a copy of a file if the content has changed to achieve a simple versioning?

```
myFolderInclSubfolderBackupWithVersioning.sh < source folder> < dest >
```

e.g
folder on source

- file1.jpg 100K (today)

folder on destination, like external HDD:

- file1.jpg size 100K (today)
- file1(2).jpg size 99K (yesterday)
- file1(1).jpg size 101K (2 monts ago)

Thank you!

Comment: You can use  `cp --backup` or `rsync --backup` and `rsync --backup-dir`. These options are described in the `man` pages for the two commands, and I recommend that you test them in a small test environment before using them, so that you know what will happen, and that it will be useful for you.

Comment: Most good backup applications will automatically determine *if the content has changed*, and won't re-backup files that have not changed. You do not need to re-invent this wheel.

Comment: Thank you! If I'd stick to cp command:
'cp -r --backup=t source target  #   rename foo → foo.jpg~1~ (or foo.jpg~2~, etc)'
is it possible to change format like this: 'foo.~1~.jpg (or foo.~2~.jpg, etc)'?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm#version-control says that backup=t and backup=numbered is the same. Do I have to use --force to aviod such a message: 'cp: 'test1.jpg' and 'test1.jpg' are the same file'?

Comment: No, you should be happy that it warns you and refuses to overwrite itself. It would probably destroy the file. The `cp --backup=t` syntax should be used when writing to another directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following setting will work:

- a working directory `work` (can have subdirectories)
- a backup directory `backup` alongside the working directory (in a real case you might have the backup directory in an external drive)

This command will backup from `work` to `backup`:

```
cp -r --backup=t work/* backup/
```

Example

```
$ find
.
./work
./work/file:name
./work/foo.sh
./work/file-0
./work/dollarfraga1
./work/dollarfraga2
./work/sub
./work/sub/hello
./work/dollarfraga
./backup
$ cp -r --backup=t work/* backup/
$ find
.
./work
./work/file:name
./work/foo.sh
./work/file-0
./work/dollarfraga1
./work/dollarfraga2
./work/sub
./work/sub/hello
./work/dollarfraga
./backup
./backup/file:name
./backup/foo.sh
./backup/file-0
./backup/dollarfraga1
./backup/dollarfraga2
./backup/sub
./backup/sub/hello
./backup/dollarfraga
$ cp -r --backup=t work/* backup/
$ find
.
./work
./work/file:name
./work/foo.sh
./work/file-0
./work/dollarfraga1
./work/dollarfraga2
./work/sub
./work/sub/hello
./work/dollarfraga
./backup
./backup/file:name
./backup/dollarfraga1.~1~
./backup/foo.sh
./backup/dollarfraga.~1~
./backup/file-0
./backup/file:name.~1~
./backup/dollarfraga1
./backup/dollarfraga2.~1~
./backup/file-0.~1~
./backup/dollarfraga2
./backup/sub
./backup/sub/hello
./backup/sub/hello.~1~
./backup/dollarfraga
./backup/foo.sh.~1~
$ cp -r --backup=t work/* backup/
$ find
.
./work
./work/file:name
./work/foo.sh
./work/file-0
./work/dollarfraga1
./work/dollarfraga2
./work/sub
./work/sub/hello
./work/dollarfraga
./backup
./backup/file:name
./backup/foo.sh.~2~
./backup/dollarfraga1.~1~
./backup/file-0.~2~
./backup/foo.sh
./backup/file:name.~2~
./backup/dollarfraga1.~2~
./backup/dollarfraga2.~2~
./backup/dollarfraga.~1~
./backup/file-0
./backup/dollarfraga.~2~
./backup/file:name.~1~
./backup/dollarfraga1
./backup/dollarfraga2.~1~
./backup/file-0.~1~
./backup/dollarfraga2
./backup/sub
./backup/sub/hello
./backup/sub/hello.~2~
./backup/sub/hello.~1~
./backup/dollarfraga
./backup/foo.sh.~1~
```

It is possible to use `cp` like this, but I would recommend, that you learn `rsync`, which is a much more advanced tool for copying directory structures including backup, or maybe some dedicated backup tool. `rsync` and those other tools will only copy files that are new or have changed.